# How reference id prints exception?

Tags: java, exception

As reference Id of an object prints the className@hash , so how does, e (a reference id of Exception class's object) prints the exception name?

```
class try1{
    public static void main(String ...args){
    try{
        int x = 10/0;
        System.out.print(x);
    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can override the `toString()` method in your `class` which allows you to return any `String` you'd like. In case of `Exceptions` they just return their class and the message. In case of `Integer`s they return their value in base 10 etc. For more explanation read the [duplicate] link

Comment: Your code should not print something className@hash? It will print java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: so actually exception classes overrides the toString method of Object class, and prints the exception? Am i right?

Comment: yeah Amit Bera, thats my question? Why does it print  java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: it's `Throwable` who override the toString in the hierarchy of ArithmaticException

Comment: Thank You Lino , i understood it now.

Answer (score -1):

When you use any object in `java System.out.println(object);` It will always call `java object.toString()` method.

[Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class is overriding the toString() method to display information for all exceptions. As all exceptions are sub classes for throwable class, exceptions will be displayed in **className:message**  format.

Internal implementation of toString() method in Throwable class.

```java
  public String toString() {
        String s = getClass().getName();
        String message = getLocalizedMessage();
        return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
    }
```

In your case ArithmeticException extends RuntimeException, RuntimeException extends Exception and Exception extends Throwable. As ArithmeticException, RuntimeException and Exception classes are not overriding toString() method. That's why Throwable toString() method is executed.

If Throwable also not override the toString() then it will execute the toString() of **java.lang.Object** which has default implementation like below

```java
 public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
 }
```

Comment: @tramboo I hope it answers your question